# Reading POST data inside an Ionic app?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have one `Ionic 3` app `(APP_1)` served via `HTTP` to the browser (not made native).

I access the `Ionic 3` application through the following url:

http://www.myionicapp.com

Then, I have another web application `(APP_2)` (not Ionic) from where I want to pass some payload data to `APP_1`. For that, I was thinking to render a form on `APP_2` like you can see below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Payload</title>
</head>
<body onload="document.form.submit();">
    <form method="post" action="https://www.myionicapp.com" name="form">
        <input type="hidden" name="payload" value="Testing123" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

where you can see I'm posting the data to the `Ionic` app.

But, when I post the data, I get the following on the browser for `APP_1`.

```
Cannot POST /
```

Is it possible to read the `POST` data inside an `Ionic` app?

What options do I have on this when needing to pass data from `APP_2` to `APP_1`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how APP_1 is being served. If it is being served via something like S3, you would need some server infrastructure to send the POST request from APP_2 to, and which APP_1 could read via a GET request.

A better way of doing it would be to use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). Integrate the [Firebase Web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) into APP2 and on form submit, programmatically [write the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write) to your Firebase Real-Time Database.

In your Ionic APP_1, use [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) to read the data submitted by APP_2. The [AngularFire Ionic 3](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/ionic/v3.md) guide and [Javebratt](https://javebratt.com/tutorials/ionic-firebase/) are great resources.